# Variables are undefined after Relay.setVariables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fragment, relay

I have a root container which has some `relayVariables`:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UsageView, {
  initialVariables: {
    start: null,
    end: null,
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: ({ start, end }) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on viewer {
        ${ProductList.getFragment('viewer', { start, end })}
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

These variables are passed down to the `ProductList` component and are used in it's fragment as well:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Component, {
  initialVariables: {
    start: null,
    end: null,
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: ({ start, end }) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on viewer {
        id
        organization {
          createdAt
          products (start: $start, end: $end) {
            name
            usageTotal
            ${ProductListItem.getFragment('data', { start, end })}
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

As you can see, these are then passed down to another component `ProductListItem`.

**All data is fetched, loaded, and rendered just fine the first time the page is loaded**. I have a dropdown which allows the user to change the **start** and **end** values, which proceeds to call `relay.setVariables` in the parent container:

```
setDateRange = ({ start, end }) => {
  this.props.relay.setVariables({
    start,
    end,
  }, (state) => {
    console.log('READYSTATE CHANGE', state);
  });
}
```

When this function is called, the `onReadyStateChange` is called 4 times, with this sequence of messages:

1. "NETWORK_QUERY_START"
2. "CACHE_RESTORE_START"
3. "CACHE_RESTORE_FAILED"
4. "NETWORK_QUERY_RECEIVED_ALL"

After this completes, the values of **start** and **end** are `undefined`, causing everything to break.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening, as the values being set to **start** and **end** in `setVariables` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was not using the input of the `setDateRange` function correctly -- It was being passed a JSON string and needed to be parsed. Unfortunately, there was no way to tell from the relay request that this was the issue...